# Bringing one point to the front in matplotlib 3D scatter

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, scatter3d

I am trying to bring the star to the front in the following plot. I tried `zorder`, but it does not work. Do you have any suggestion?

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))

ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.zaxis.get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(True)
#ax.zaxis.set_rotate_label(False)
#ax.yaxis.set_rotate_label(False)
#ax.xaxis.set_rotate_label(False)

ax.scatter(optim_index[np.argmin(optim_val)][0], optim_index[np.argmin(optim_val)][1], min(optim_val),
           marker = '*', color = 'green', s=100, zorder=10, label = 'Optimal Solution')
ax.scatter(Plist, Vlist, Objlist, marker = '.', color = 'grey',label='Infeasible Solution')
ax.scatter(Feas_P, Feas_V, Objval, marker = '.', color = 'royalblue', label='Feasible Solution')


ax.view_init(30, 40)
ax.set_xlabel('Laser Power (W)', rotation = 6)
ax.set_ylabel('Scan Speed (mm/s)', rotation = -30)
ax.set_zlabel('Objective Value ($)', rotation = 92)
ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.7, 0.8),
          fancybox=True, shadow=False, ncol=1, scatterpoints = 1, fontsize=10)

plt.show() # Deactivate me to save the plot
#plt.savefig('ParamOptim.png', format='png') #dpi=900)  #Activate me to save the plot
```

[image]

Comment: what happens if you plot that point last instead of first?

Comment: I tried all the combinations of ordering. They do not change it.

Comment: I think this is one the 3D problems that cannot even be solved using zorder. There are already similar questions around, so maybe someone has found a clever workaround and provided an answer to those.